# Add a TemplaVoila FCE via typoscript in typo3

Tags: blogs, typo3, templavoila

I have a typo3 with a TemplaVoila template. The varios page layouts like full, with sidebar are FCE. For normal pages this is fine but I want to insert a blog (typo3_blog) into my page.

For this i want a certain layout (page with sidebar) which all blog pages should have. 
I can't just add the FCE for all blog pages because the extension is using all added FCE as blog content.

So how can i add the FCE to the page using typoscript? Or is there ab etter way to do this?

The only alternative way I could think of is definign a whole new page template but I don't want to map a whole template just for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding FCE by typoscript is very simple,

This code will get your content element with ID 133, so it may be Your FCE

```
lib.tsfce = COA
lib.tsfce {
    10 = RECORDS
    10 {
        tables = tt_content
        source = 133
    }
}
```

If You want to get a collection of contents from any subpage, try this snippet

```
lib.aside_mistif = COA
lib.aside_mistif {
    1 = CONTENT
    1 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            pidInList = 41
        }
    }
}
```

or You can use this extension http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kb_tv_cont_slide
to slide aside from parent page